# File download in php, memory limit problem?

Tags: php, apache, file, memory, limit

A client of mine decided to move the website from a somewhat nice server to a... lets call it lesser nice server.

The problem is, there's a file with 40MBs to be downloaded and the memory limit on the server is 32. To make it even more difficult for me, they don't allow fopen...

Also, if i reduce the file size to 20MB it works fine.

So, my question is, what can i do - besides reducing the file size - to make this work?

Thank you

EDIT:`

```
        $fsize = filesize($file_path);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);


        switch ($ext) {
            case "pdf": $ctype = "application/pdf";
                break;
            case "exe": $ctype = "application/octet-stream";
                break;
            case "zip": $ctype = "application/zip";
                break;
            case "doc": $ctype = "application/msword";
                break;
            case "xls": $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case "ppt": $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
                break;
            case "gif": $ctype = "image/gif";
                break;
            case "png": $ctype = "image/png";
                break;
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg": $ctype = "image/jpg";
                break;
            default: $ctype = "application/force-download";
        }

        header("Pragma: public"); // required
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
        header("Content-Type: $ctype");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_path) . "\";");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file_path);`
```

The code i saw on php.net

```
// If it's a large file, readfile might not be able to do it in one go, so:
$chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024); // how many bytes per chunk
if ($size > $chunksize) {
  $handle = fopen($realpath, 'rb');
  $buffer = '';
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
    echo $buffer;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
  }
  fclose($handle);
} else {
  readfile($realpath);
}
```

Comment: What's the core section of your phpinfo look like? Could you paste it? If you're looking for a quick fix, you may be able to change your php settings using an .htaccess file. They're drupal docs, but they are not drupal specific.  http://drupal.org/node/29268 and http://drupal.org/node/97193

Comment: Any part in particular? (it's kinda big to post everything here)

Comment: the code from php.net should do fine. just strip out ob_.. if not used. If ob, consider adding gz for faster download.

Comment: Can or not use fopen??? In the code you r using it

Comment: The code i use is the first. In response to the comment of Marc B (below) i posted what i found on php.net stating that for larger files i should use fopen and a buffer. I cannot use fopen on that "gorram" server.

Comment: @MarioCesar If the code you found on php.net solved your issue, you should post it as an answer and accept it. It worked for me and I would have voted it up.

Comment: The code found didn't solved my question. It was the code I mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) instead. It'll stream the file in small chunks and handle all the background work to keep memory usage minimal.

Comment: well i'm allready using the readfile() function. :/ I mentioned the fopen function because i read in the php.net that to handle a situation like mine I should use the fopen function and a buffer... i'll post my code

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests `readfile` buffers file chunks. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I can't "accept" the answer cos it really doesn't resolve my problem, but i found it useful. Thank you.

Comment: -1, readfile() does *not* chunk by default. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#99406

Answer (score 0):

You really want [`fpassthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) but if the host disabled `fopen()` they probably disabled `fpassthru()`, too. In that case you either negotiate with the host or start to look for a better host. Or you cannot distribute big files at all.

It sounds to me that the host is intentionally crippling the available features to reduce bandwidth costs and/or CPU usage. If they allow any files to be read it should not be about security rules.